# Can Postgres use a function in a partial index where clause?

Tags: function, postgresql, indexing

I have a large Postgres table where I want to partial index on 1 of the 2 columns indexed. Can I and how do I use a Postgres function in the where clause of a partial index and then have the select query utilize that partial index?

**Example Scenario**

First column is "magazine" and the second column is "volume" and the third column is "issue". All the magazines can have same "volume" and "issue" #'s but I want the index to only contain the two most recent volumes for that magazine. This is because a magazine could be older than others and have higher volume numbers than younger magazines.

Two immutable strict functions were created to determine the current and last years volumes for a magazine f_current_volume('gq') and f_previous_volume('gq'). Note: current/past volume # only changes once per year.

I tried creating a partial index with the functions however when using explain on a query it only does a seq scan for a current volume magazine.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_issue_magazine_volume ON issue USING BTREE ( magazine, volume ) 
  WHERE volume IN (f_current_volume(magazine), f_previous_volume(magazine));

-- Both these do seq scans.
select * from issue where magazine = 'gq' and volume = 100;
select * from issue where magazine = 'gq' and volume = f_current_volume('gq');
```

What am I doing wrong to get this work? And if it is possible why does it need to be done that way for Postgres to use the index?

```
-- UPDATE: 2013-06-17, the following surprisingly used the index.
-- Why would using a field name rather than value allow the index to be used?
select * from issue where magazine = 'gq' and volume = f_current_volume(magazine);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Immutability and 'current'

If your `f_current_volume` function ever changes its behaviour - as is implied by its name, and the presence of an `f_previous_volume` function, then the database is free to return *completely bogus results*.

PostgreSQL would've refused to let you create the index, complaining that you can only use `IMMUTABLE` functions. The thing is, marking a function `IMMUTABLE` means that *you* are telling *PostgreSQL* something about the function's behaviour, as per the documentation. You're saying "I promise this function's results won't change, feel free to make assumptions on that basis."

One of the biggest assumptions made is when building an index. If the function returns different outputs for different inputs on multiple invocations, things go *splat*. Or possibly *boom* if you're unlucky. In theory you can kind-of get away with changing an immutable function by `REINDEX`ing everything, but the only really safe way is to `DROP` every index that uses it, `DROP` the function, re-create the function with its new definition and re-create the indexes.

That can actually be really useful to do if you have something that changes only infrequently, but you really have two different immutable functions at different points in time that just happen to have the same name.

### Partial index matching

PostgreSQL's partial index matching is pretty dumb - but, as I found when writing test cases for this, a lot smarter than it used to be. It ignores a dummy `OR true`. It uses an index on `WHERE (a%100=0 OR a%1000=0)` for a `WHERE a = 100` query. It even got it with a non-inline-able identity function:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE partial AS SELECT x AS a, x 
          AS b FROM generate_series(1,10000) x;
regress=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION identity(integer) 
          RETURNS integer AS $$
          SELECT $1; 
          $$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
regress=> CREATE INDEX partial_b_fn_idx 
          ON partial(b) WHERE (identity(b) % 1000 = 0);
regress=> EXPLAIN SELECT b FROM partial WHERE b % 1000 = 0;
                                      QUERY PLAN                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using partial_b_fn_idx on partial  (cost=0.00..13.05 rows=50 width=4)
(1 row)
```

However, it was unable to prove the `IN` clause match, eg:

```
regress=> DROP INDEX partial_b_fn_idx;
regress=> CREATE INDEX partial_b_fn_in_idx ON partial(b)
          WHERE (b IN (identity(b), 1));
regress=> EXPLAIN SELECT b FROM partial WHERE b % 1000 = 0;
                               QUERY PLAN                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on partial  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000195.00 rows=50 width=4)
```

So my advice? Rewrite `IN` as an `OR` list:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_issue_magazine_volume ON issue USING BTREE ( magazine, volume ) 
  WHERE (volume = f_current_volume(magazine) OR volume = f_previous_volume(magazine));
```

... and on a current version it might just work, so long as you keep the immutability rules outlined above in mind. Well, the second version:

```
select * from issue where magazine = 'gq' and volume = f_current_volume('gq');
```

might. *Update*: No, it won't; for it to be used, Pg would have to recognise that `magazine='gq'` and realise that `f_current_volume('gq')` was therefore equiavalent to `f_current_volume(magazine)`. It doesn't attempt to prove equivalences on that level with partial index matching, so as you've noted in your update you have to write `f_current_volume(magazine)` directly. I should've spotted that. In theory PostgreSQL could use the index with the second query if the planner was smart enough, but I'm not sure how you'd go about efficiently looking for places where a substitution like this would be worthwhile.

The first example, `volume = 100` will never use the index, since at query planning time PostgreSQL has no idea that `f_current_volumne('gg');` will evaluate to `100`. You could add an OR clause `OR volume = 100` to your partial index `WHERE` clause and PostgreSQL would figure it out then, though.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. In this scenario "volume" would change once a year so only volatile once a year. I was able to get it to work (using the IN clause) by having the select query have the column name rather than a specific value. i.e. "select * from issue where magazine = 'gq' and volume = f_current_volume(magazine);". Why is this?

Comment: Also to note, rewriting the "IN" as an "OR" list for the where clause in the index didn't work. I'm running version 9.2.2.

Comment: @thames Re why the column name vs specific value: because that's how the `where` clause is written in the partial index. I really should've spotted that in the original example you gave, but it's all down to the same thing: An expression index will only be used if there's a matching expression in the query. Your index isn't `where ... f_current_volume('gq')`, it's `where ... f_current_volume(magazine)`. You're expecting Pg to prove that since you wrote 'magazine = 'gq'` then `f_current_volume('gq')` and `f_current_volume(magazine)` are equivalent. It doesn't attempt that.

Comment: @thames I'm extremely surprised that the partial index is used though the `IN` clause, given that I was unable to show that happening at all in my testing.

Comment: Just in case support goes away or it is just a fluke, I've changed the "IN" clause to the "OR" clause as recommended by you. Still works.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd like to volunteer a wild guess, because you're making it sound like your `f_current_volume()` function calculates something based on a separate table.

If so, be wary because this means your function `volatile`, in that it needs to be recalculated on every call (a concurrent transaction might be inserting, updating or deleting rows). Postgres won't allow to index those, and I presume you worked around this by declaring the function `immutable`. Not only is this incorrect, but you also run into the issue of the index containing garbage, because the function gets evaluated as you edit the row, rather than at run time. What you'd probably want instead -- again if my guess is correct -- is to store and maintain the totals in the table itself using triggers.

Regarding your specific question, partial indexes need to have their where condition be met in the query to prompt Postgres to use them. I'm quite sure that Postgres is smart enough to identify that e.g. `10` is `between 5 and 15` and use a partial index with that clause. I'm very suspicious that it would know that `f_current_volume('gq')` is 100 in your case, however, considering the above-mentioned caveat.

You could try this query and see if the index gets used:

```
select *
  from issue
 where magazine = 'gq'
   and volume in (f_current_volume('gq'), f_previous_volume('gq'));
```

(Though again, if your function is in fact volatile, you'll get a seq scan as well.)

Comment: Actually a function producing results based on another table is `STABLE` so long as the *current* transaction isn't modifying that table (and even then, in most cases, the modification will happen in a later phase). Concurrent transactions aren't an issue here because they're not visible in the statement's snapshot. It doesn't make much difference in this case since neither `volatile` nor `stable` functions are indexable.

Comment: @Denis - In this scenario current "volume" only changes once a year. Also note that I was able to get it to work by using the column name rather than value in the function. i.e. "select * from issue where magazine = 'gq' and volume = f_current_volume(magazine);"