# Is there anyway to make the unique index ignore old data?

Tags: postgresql

What I need to do is to block rows from being duplicade at the values number, serie and model.
My initial thought was to do something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_fiscal_number
ON Fiscal(number, serie, model);
```

The problem is that this database is really old, and there's a lot of data already duplicated. So my question is:
Is there anyway to make this unique index start validating now and accept the old data already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a partial index if you can express the condition "old" with existing columns. For example, if you have a column "age"

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_fiscal_number_partial 
ON fiscal(number, serie, model)
WHERE age < 1000;
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html.

Comment: I have a column where I've a serial primary key. But as I was trying it stumbled into another problem: I've thousands of schemas with this table, so after doing some research (I'm not used to working with sql) isn't there maybe a trigger that could do the work?

Comment: I don't think trigger can help for indexing. If you have the same index to be created in a lot of schemas you can automate this wtih PL/PGSQL (create a loop on all schemas to execute the index creation).

Comment: I think that the in the end `where age < 1000` would work really well, but the problem would be that each table has an "age" of it's own. Is there anything like `WHERE age > max(age)`, that I could use?

Comment: I don't know if you can have a kind of subquery in the WHERE clause of the partial index. I know you can call a function but i am not sure it can work for UNIQUE index: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116795/can-postgres-use-a-function-in-a-partial-index-where-clause.

Comment: I just figure that I have a "date" column, so I'll just use it and it's going to work like a charm. Thanks for the help

Comment: is it ok if we leave the old data without intention to correct it? so we never remove the condition from our index